# app activity privacy and app_non_users

Tags: facebook, android-activity, privacy

When using the request dialogue and using `app_non_users` if a person sets their app activity privacy to anything other than public, their name shows under `app_non_users` and will not show up under the only app users.

Is there a fix for this or is this a bug as it basically makes `app_non_users` redundant and absolutely uselss ?

Comment: i don't think it makes app_non_users redundant, it makes sense, since app activity determines that we know if a user is using an app or not.IMHO :)

Answer (score 0):

The privacy settings of a user are respected in this endpoint, so if user A and user B both use the app, and are friends, but user B's privacy selection for the app is 'Only Me' or otherwise excludes user A, user A will not see user B as a user of the app in the 'App users' filter of the dialog